# Executing Dynamic SQL Using A Results Set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I want to construct a dynamic SQL statement. I have several databases that are exact clones of each other e.g. TestDatabase1 is the same as TestDatabase2 and etc. Since the schemas and tables in all of the cloned databases are exactly the same, I want to execute a SQL statement that updates each table. Here's the pseudo-code:

```
for each table x in a test database
update x.SomeColumn
```

I have code to grab the databases:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name LIKE '%Test%'
```

but now I don't know what to do with that data. How can I update each table in each database?

Comment: How are you planning to update the data? what criteria will you use to filter rows or calculate new values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_MSforeachtable` to run Update statements against every table in a database. For example:

```
-- First set the database you want to use:
USE TempDatabase1
GO

    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE ? SET SomeColumn = 2' 

GO

USE TempDatabase2
GO

    EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE ? SET SomeColumn = 2' 
GO
```

Comment: If the databases are named "TempDatabase1", "TempDatabase2", etc. how can i select only those databases?

Comment: You can set the current database with the USE statement. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do that by dynamically instead of declaring each use statement? I have a situation where temporary databases are added and removed at any time, so that's why I'm using the select statement and filtering by the string "test" in the database name.

Comment: You can use `sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?];'`